# Override SaveAs Method of foreign Program/Process

Tags: c#, overriding

Idea of the Program:

I´m developing a WinForm-Application in C-Sharp .NET-4 which will allow me to import a Folder with Files and Subfolders into a MySQL-Database and also show me these Files and Folders in an Explorer-like set of Treeview and Listview. By a Double-Click on a Filename in the Listview, the file will opened with the default Program.

The Main-Goal of this Software is to be a Multiuser-Project-Manager.

The Problem:

Once the file is opened, its outside of my Program. I can´t control the foreign Program.

The Question:

Is there a way to override/control for instance the SaveAs-Method of such foreign Proram to save the File under my conditions e.g. to save them back to my database and not to the filesystem.

I´m grateful for any answer.

Comment: Maybe have a look at using a FileSystemWatcher http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx to check if anything happened to the file?

Comment: That would only work if the file would be saved to it self, but not if the file is saved under a different name in a different folder and so on